# Regex for first two character of String should be GE | TE | WN | TA | UE | BW and Next two character should be RU |MT | LD

Tags: jquery, regex

I need a regex for the field validation with four letters in jquery. In which it accepts first two should be `GE | TE | WN | TA | UE | BW`  and next two character should be `RU |MT | LD`

Example:

```
GELD (Valid)
EGLD (Invalid)
TEMT (valid)       
TETM (invalid)
```

My Regex:

```
 ([GE|TE|WN|TA|UE|BW]{2}[RU|MT|LD]{2})
```

this is not correct it accepts all the values between with these alphabets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two separate alternations:

```
(?:GE|TE|WN|TA|UE|BW)(?:RU|MT|LD)
```

You made a fairly common mistake of thinking that `[RU|MT|LD]` means `RU`, `MT`, or `LD`.  It does not, but actually means `[DLMRTU]`, i.e. one of those six letters.

### Demo

You might want to also surround your pattern with starting and ending anchors, e.g. if you want to restrict the entire input to match:

```
^(?:GE|TE|WN|TA|UE|BW)(?:RU|MT|LD)$
```